# How to copy object value in array to another empty array in javascript/lodash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have the following array,

`var users = [{_id : "qwertyuiop"}, {_id: "asdfghj1kl"}, {_id : "zxcvbnm123"}];`

My expected result is  `["qwertyuiop", "asdfghj1kl", "zxcvbnm123"];`

Instead of using foreach and pushing to array, I wonder is there any other way to get this result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those problems where vanilla javascript is best (unless you're chaining).

```
users.map(({_id}) => _id) // destructuring w/ arrow fnc
---
users.map(x => x._id) // arrow fnc
---
users.map(function(x) { return x._id} ) // es5
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pluck`](https://lodash.com/docs/2.4.2#pluck) in lodash

```
var users = [{_id : "qwertyuiop"}, {_id: "asdfghj1kl"}, {_id : "zxcvbnm123"}];
_.pluck(users, '_id'); // → ["qwertyuiop", "asdfghj1kl", "zxcvbnm123"]
```

```js
var users = [{_id : "qwertyuiop"}, {_id: "asdfghj1kl"}, {_id : "zxcvbnm123"}];
console.log(_.pluck(users, '_id')); // → ["qwertyuiop", "asdfghj1kl", "zxcvbnm123"]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.2.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```